# How to create a multi-variable "ts" object in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have have a dataframe of two different time series. I am able to create ts object separately with the following command:

Data Frame:

```
    Year Grocery_Stores Liquor
1 Feb-11         1953.8  216.8
2 Mar-11         2108.1  240.5
3 Apr-11         2062.3  244.4
4 May-11         2034.8  232.1
5 Jun-11         1988.6  223.6
6 Jul-11         2085.9  239.0

Ts_grocery <- ts(dataFeed$Grocery_Stores, frequency=12, start=c(2011,2))
Ts_Liquor <- ts(dataFeed$Liquor, frequency=12, start=c(2011,2))
```

I want to bind this to and create a multi-variable time series "ts" object for my VAR model. I tried some possibilities but its not working. How I will be able to make one "ts" object? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: pls run `dput(dataFeed)` and share the output with us.

Comment: @BigDataScientist I do not know why you are asking, but it gives me following list:
>dput(head(dataFeed))

structure(list(Year = c("Feb-11", "Mar-11", "Apr-11", "May-11", 
"Jun-11", "Jul-11"), Grocery_Stores = c(1953.8, 2108.1, 2062.3, 
2034.8, 1988.6, 2085.9), Liquor = c(216.8, 240.5, 244.4, 232.1, 
223.6, 239)), .Names = c("Year", "Grocery_Stores", "Liquor"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ts.union(Ts_grocery, Ts_Liquor)`.  That's the first answer you find when you google *can you bind several timeseries in r* and it seems to work.

Comment: There's a `ts.intersect` option as well, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: That's a nice way, I did not know about it. It works, Thank you. As I already have data frame, so I have preferred directly converting it to ts object with 
`ts(dataFeed[-1], start = c(2011, 2), freq = 12)`
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**data frame to ts**

If the problem is how to convert `datafeed` to a `"ts"` series then:

```
ts(dataFeed[-1], start = c(2011, 2), freq = 12)
```

or read it into a zoo object and then convert it to `"ts"` class using `as.ts` (or depending on what you want to do just use `z`).  `FUN = as.yearmon` converts the index to year/month and the `format` specifiers `%b` and `%y` mean month abbreviation and 2 digit year.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(dataFeed, FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%b-%y")
as.ts(z)
```

The second method using zoo has the advantage of derving the start value from the series itself.

**bind ts series**

If the problem is how to bind two `"ts"` series together then:

```
cbind(Ts_Liquor, Ts_grocery)
```

**Note:**  The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "Year Grocery_Stores Liquor
1 Feb-11         1953.8  216.8
2 Mar-11         2108.1  240.5
3 Apr-11         2062.3  244.4
4 May-11         2034.8  232.1
5 Jun-11         1988.6  223.6
6 Jul-11         2085.9  239.0"

dataFeed <- read.table(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: @Grothendieck, I was looking for the first line of code. It is working. Thank you a lot.